# How to implement tasks with two awaiting points, using async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have some asynchronous operations that consist of two distinct stages. Initially I want to `await` them until the completion of their first stage, and later `await` them until their final completion. Here is a simplified version of these operations:

```
async Task<string> TwoStagesAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Started");
    await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
    bool resultOfStage1 = true;
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Finished");
    if (!resultOfStage1) return null;
    /* Stage separator */
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Started");
    await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Finished");
    return "Hello!";
}
```

To achieve this requirement I had the idea of representing these two-stage operations as nested tasks: `Task<Task<string>>`. This would allow me to `await` initially the outer task, and later `await` the result of the outer task, which would be the inner task. This is my currently best attempt to implement this idea:

```
async Task<Task<string>> TwoStagesNestedAsync_A() // Problematic
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Started");
    await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
    bool resultOfStage1 = true;
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Finished");
    if (!resultOfStage1) return Task.FromResult((string)null);
    /* Stage separator */
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Started");
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Finished");
        return "Hello!";
    });
}
```

What I like to this solution is that it works and it is quite readable, since it doesn't require any special synchronization primitives like `SemaphoreSlim` or `TaskCompletionSource`. What I don't like is that the second stage is executed in the `ThreadPool` context instead of the initial [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext). Is there any way to make it use the current `SynchronizationContext` from start to finish, without complicating it too much?

I should include one more of my failed attempts. Replacing the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) with a [local async function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) doesn't work, because for some reason the line `Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Started")` is executed as part of the first stage, instead of the second stage.

```
async Task<Task<string>> TwoStagesNestedAsync_B() // Problematic
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Started");
    await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
    bool resultOfStage1 = true;
    Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Finished");
    if (!resultOfStage1) return Task.FromResult((string)null);
    return SecondStageAsync();

    async Task<string> SecondStageAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Started");
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Finished");
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Here is an example of consuming an asynchronous operation that consists of two stages:

```
Task<Task<string>>[] operations = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(_ => TwoStagesNestedAsync_A())
    .ToArray();

/* Do something else before awaiting Stage 1 */

Task<string>[] innerTasks = await Task.WhenAll(operations);
Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 is now complete");

/* Do something else before awaiting Stage 2 */

string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(innerTasks);
Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 is now complete");
```

Comment: What is the issue with your original code sample? Awaiting one operation after another seems legit approach.

Comment: @Fabio the initial simple approach `TwoStagesAsync` doesn't allow me to await the resulting task until the completion of its first stage. I can only await it until its final completion.

Comment: Can you show an example of how such method would be consumed?

Comment: If you want to "do something" with the result of first stage or when first stage is complete, then you can pass a function or action to the method and execute it after first stage is complete.

Comment: @Fabio I updated my question with an example of a consuming scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to execute something when first stage is complete.
You can pass an action as parameter to the function.

```cs
public async Task<string> TwoStagesAsync(Func<Task> injectedAction)
{
    await ExecuteStageOne();

    // Execute without "stopping" second stage
    var injectedTask = injectedAction.Invoke();

    if (somethingFailed) return null;
    /* Stage separator */

    await ExecuteStageTwo();

    await injectedTask; // Make sure it completes without errors
    return "Hello!";
}
```

**After update**
Requirements tell us that consumer of the `TwoStages` method do know that operation has two stages and this consumer want execute some action between every stage.
So we need to expose tasks of every state to the consumer.
If you wrap `TwoStages` method within a class, you can expose more details for its consumers.
We write code in object-oriented programming language anyway, isn't it ;)

```
public class TwoStageOperation
{
    public TwoStageOperation() { }

    public async Task ExecuteFirstStage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Started");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Finished");
    }

    public async Task<string> ExecuteLastStage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Started");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Finished");

        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var operations = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(_ => new TwoStageOperation())
    .ToArray();

/* Do something else before awaiting Stage 1 */


await Task.WhenAll(operations.Select(op => op.ExecuteFirstStage());
Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 is now complete");

/* Do something else before awaiting Stage 2 */

string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(operations.Select(op => op.ExecuteLastStage());
Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 is now complete");
```

In case operations has different implementations, you can introduce an interface and have different implementations

```
public interface ITwoStageOperation
{
    Task ExecuteFirstStage();
    Task<string> ExecuteLastStage();
}

var operations = new ITwoStageOperation[]
{
    new LandTwoStageOperation(),
    new OceanTwoStageOperation(),
    new AirTwoStageOperation(),
};
```

**Alternative approach**
Which I think you will prefer more, because you were very close to it :), would be to return a function as result of first stage

```
public async Task<Func<Task<string>>> TwoStagesAsync()
{
    await ExecuteStageOne();

    Func<Task<string>> lastStage = async () =>
    {
         await Task.Delay(1000);
         return "Hello";
    };

    return lastStage;
}
```

Usage

```
var firstStages = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(_ => TwoStagesAsync())
    .ToArray();

/* Do something else before awaiting Stage 1 */

var lastStages = await Task.WhenAll(firstStages);
Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 is now complete");

/* Do something else before awaiting Stage 2 */

string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(lastStages.Select(s => s.Invoke());
Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 is now complete");
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio for the answer. This is a viable solution, but it complicates the consumption of the operation. I would prefer to consume it in a natural async/await fashion if possible (avoiding explicit continuations).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I think you were close with the approach of local function. Check my last alternative approach where `TwoStagesAsync` method returns a function of the next stage.

Comment: Regarding the `TwoStageOperation` class approach, I will consider it for my use case, but TBH I was hopping for a simpler technique that I can use anywhere, without having to carry the "weight" of an extra class. Something that also doesn't fit my requirements is the need to initiate manually the second stage of the operation. I want both stages to execute sequentially the one after the other, irrespective of the moment that I'll decide to await them. In other words it is quite possible that both stages may have already been completed at the time that I'll await the first one.

Comment: You are probably right though that the approach with the local function is what I want after all, and there may be nothing simpler than that.

Comment: "Weight" of an extra class - sorry, wasn't aware of such issue ;) Classes are our tools same as methods variables and classes weight nothing, but provide encapsulation for some implementation details you want to hide from the consumer of the class.

Comment: Anyway, you need to expose both stages to the consumer somehow

Comment: Yeap, "weight" may be a wrong word. What I wanted to say is that if I can do the same thing equally well with and without a class, then doing it without a class is probably preferable. Less classes => less code => less opportunities for something to go wrong. 

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
public static async Task<bool> FirstStageAsync() // Problematic
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Started");
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
        bool resultOfStage1 = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 1 Finished");
        return await Task.FromResult(resultOfStage1);
    }

    public static async Task<string> SecondStageAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Started");
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate an I/O operation
        Console.WriteLine($"Stage 2 Finished");
        return "Hello!";
    }
```

Then you can call it by:

```
var task = FirstStageAsync().ContinueWith(async d =>
        {
            if (d.IsCompleted)
            {
                var resultOfStage1 = await d;
                if (resultOfStage1)
                {
                    var task2 = SecondStageAsync();
                    task2.Wait();
                }
            }
        });

        task.Wait();
```

Is that you want to achieve?

Be careful with deadlock.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Pujangga for the answer! I would like to avoid using the `ContinueWith` method in combination with async/await, because [it is known](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) to have problems. Also from my understanding the continuation of `ContinueWith` will not run in the same `SynchronizationContext` as the first stage, but I may be wrong about it.

Comment: My code just want to try simulate your case in a simple way. If you doing it right then there is no dangerous code. I play a lot with async/await and ContinueWith so far and yes there are risks but I am the lucky guy I guess. :)