# Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew - Expected Deadlock is not happening

Tags: c#, async-await, task, deadlock

I read about the differences of Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew.

```
Task.Run(() => {});
```

should be equivalent to

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

But in my code I expect a deadlock which is not happening because of Task.Factory.StartNew:

```
private Task backgroundTask;

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   // this should deadlock
   await this.backgroundTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
   throw new Exception();
}

private async Task Test()
{
   this.backgroundTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
      {
         await this.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
      }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

   // just wait here for testing/debugging
   await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
   // if no deadlock, this should throw
   await this.backgroundTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

But it is not deadlocking. The exception in DoSomethingAsync is thrown but never catched.
Awaiting the Task after the Task.Delay is not throwing either, because it is RanToCompletion.

When using Task.Run it is deadlocking as expected:

```
private Task backgroundTask;

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   // this is deadlocking
   await this.backgroundTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
   throw new Exception();
}

private async Task Test()
{
   this.backgroundTask= Task.Run(async () =>
      {
         await this.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
      });

   // just wait here for testing/debugging
   await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
   // never reached because of deadlock
   await this.backgroundTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: Have read this article? [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `Task.Factory.StartNew` when used with an async delegate returns a nested task: `Task<Task>`. You are assigning this nested task to a variable of type `Task`, which is allowed because the class `Task<TResult>` derives from the class `Task`. What happens then is that you lose the reference to the inner task, so you have no way of awaiting it. When you `await this.backgroundTask` you are awaiting the outer `Task<Task>`, but you can't get the result of the await operation, which is a `Task`, the inner `Task`, and `await` it. The inner task has become a fire-and-forget task.

Comment: That would explain the behaviour.
But when is the Task<Task> (outer task) RanToCompletion, what does it mean?

Comment: @AlteGurke the outer Task completes when the delegate reaches the first `await`, this is because then the call to the delegate returns the Task object which represents the async wait.

Comment: @AlteGurke when the `Task<Task>` completes, it means that the inner task has just been created. Usually creating a task is not much work to do, so having a task that creates another task doesn't make much sense. This is why the `Task.Run` method when supplied with an async delegate combines the two tasks in one, and returns a "proxy" task that completes when both the outer and the inner tasks are completed. But you may encounter some rare cases where using a `Task<Task>` makes sense, like when you want a task with [two awaiting points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981628) for example.